# R simulation calling second program.

Tags: r, simulation, terminate

I am running a simulation in R. I generate my data within R then I use R to call a second program (which is called using the command prompt) to run my analysis on the generated data.  The second program occasionally crashes and a pop up comes on the screen to close the program thus stopping the simulation in its tracks.

Is it possible have R recognize that the simulation has stopped because of the secondary program crashing and continue to run (i.e. Fork package)?  Is this similar to the parent-child relationship I've seen described in c?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `R` crash or simply hang (i.e. you could get control back via <ESC> or the STOP button)?  If your `R` command is waiting for the called program to terminate, I don't think there's a way for `R` to simultaneously monitor your process table or equivalent.

Comment: R is just hanging out since the child program crashed. Thank you for the information!